# Group ring definition

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-rings

I don't understand the definition of a group ring. In "An Introduction to Group Rings" by Polcino and Sehgal (page 129), an element of the group ring $RG$ is a linear combination of elements from $G$ and coefficients from $R$ (here $R$ is a ring a $G$ is a group). In the samo book, at page 131 it says that an element of the group ring $RG$ is a mapping $\alpha:G \to R$ with $supp(\alpha)< \infty $. I don't understand the connection between these two definitions. A linear combination is a map? The value of a linear combination $\sum_{g\in G} a_g*g$ is an element from $R$?

Comment: The "linear combination" is an afterthought. First you have to construct an $R$-module in which the "elements of $G$" can be combined. That's the module of mappings from $G$ to $R$ with finite support. This is analogous to the definition of polynomials in one variable (say, $x$): First you define them as sequences of coefficients; then you call a very specific such sequence $x$ and define multiplication; only then can you say that polynomials are linear combinations of $x^0, x^1, x^2, \ldots$.

Comment: But why is that module, the module of mappings? After all, I want to define g*r not some mappings

Comment: The linear combination $\sum a_gg$ corresponds to the map that takes $g$ in $G$ to $a_g$ in $R$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson that's makes sense. Thank you!